# What is this indication

Tags: trains, athens

Today on Green Line of Athens Metro at Kiffisia Station I noticed this in Vehicle Indication:

[image: Indication isndie the vehicle]

And I was wandering what the *D8L19A* means. It is shown when the rail starts a new route on the Green line just after the operator starts the locomotive. I have no Idea what system is used or what model the Green Line uses but it is rather old.

Please keep in mind that in Kifisia station is the Begining of the line.

Comment: It is probably not supposed to be meaningful for passengers (or even employees), just a low-lever diagnostic display while the system is rebooting (which it may well need to when the driver changes cabs).

Comment: I wonder what written on display means as a diagnostic message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a diagnostic message that is of absolutely no use for travelers. That's all there is to it.